# How to stop Postgres from auto update on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, updates, postgresql

I was using Postgres 9.5.6 for my personal project and today when I logged in to Postgres, the version was 9.5.8 which also caused an auto restart.

I would like to know how to stop a package (Postgres specifically) from auto updating itself on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In the software center, you can search for the package, choose a specific version and specify the system should not use another version even if there's a new one.

Comment: This can be done easily on local machine. But what about an aws machine where my application is hosted on?!

Comment: @WasimThabraze Please check the questions we linked in the comments to your question, I think they will help you.

Comment: Need a command line solution, for a server